# problema de array PHP, el echo me muestra array

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 while (true) {
     $t= "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM accidente";

        $query2=mysqli_query($db,$t);
        while($acd[]=mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
```

`$last= current($last_id);
$acd_1=current($acd);
 $ls=(( $last !== false) ? $last : ", &nbsp;");
 $acd2=(( $acd_1 !== false) ? $acd_1 : ", &nbsp;");
                $valores3='("'.$ls.'","'.$acd2.'"),';
                $valoresQ3= substr($valores3, 0, -1);


            $acd_impl="INSERT INTO implicado_acd (id_acd, id_implicado) VALUES $valoresQ3";
            $sqlRess1=$db->query($acd_impl) or mysql_error();

    $last = next($last_id);
    $acd_1= next($acd);
    if($last === false) break;
                        echo "...".$acd;`

Comment: disculpa podrias describir el problema en si , que error te sale.

Comment: La idea es que tome un numero y el error que muestra dice array to string conversion y muestra en el ultimo echo "Array"

Comment: Puedes explicar tu codigo? no esta bien indentado y da lugar a confusiones (aparte de los nombres de variables, por ej: que es un **acd**? El ultimo echo te muestra **Array** porque eso es lo que guardas en el segundo while. Prueba con **print_r($acd);** y veras el contenido de ese array.

Comment: Siempre que intentes ver el contenido de un array usando `echo $array`, lo único que verás en pantalla será: `array`. Para ver lo que contiene el array puedes usar: `print_r(), var_dump() o var_export()`. Puedes ver esta pregunta y sus respuestas para más detalles: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre echo, print, print_r, var_dump y var_export en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/29967)  _Nota:_ +1 para revertir el voto negativo, no me gustan los talibanes de SO, no hay motivo para votar en contra esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Cómo bien comenta NetVicious con:

- Print_r : Imprime información legible para humanos sobre una variable
- Var_dump : Muestra información sobre una variable

  ```
  print_r($array);    var_dump($array);
  ```

Ambas funciones internas de php te ayudarán a mostrar el contenido del array en una línea.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el:

```
echo "..." . $acd;
```

Por un

```
print_r($acd);
```

Ya que tu problema es que estas intentando hacer un echo de un array.