# popupalert javascript y php

Tags: php, javascript

Al ejecutar este código me indica *Undefined offset* en la línea de la query.

```
<p> id="demo"></p>

                 <script>
                 function myFunction() {
                     var txt;
                     if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
                         txt = "You pressed OK!";
                     } else {
                         txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
                     }
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
                 }
                 </script>

        <?php 
             while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<tr class='success'>";
                    echo "<td>$arreglo[0]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$arreglo[1]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$arreglo[2]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$arreglo[3]</td>";
                    echo "<td>$arreglo[4]</td>";


                  //echo "<td><a href='admin_actualizar.php?id=$arreglo[0]'><button class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></button></td>";

                 echo "<td><a href='admin.php?id=$arreglo[0]&idborrar=2'><button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove' onclick='myFunction()'></button></a></td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
             echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";

                extract($_GET);
                if(@$idborrar==2){

                    $sqlborrar="DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`id_usuario` = $id";
                    $resborrar=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlborrar);
                    echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ELIMINADO")</script> ';

                    echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
                }
        ?>
```

Comment: prueba reemplazar  "DELETE FROM `usuarios` WHERE `usuarios`.`id_usuario` = $id"` por  ` "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario =". $id`

Comment: El mensaje que daría sería en la query sería *`Undefined variable`*, porque no veo que `$id` sea declarado en ninguna parte. [El mensaje *`Undefined offset`* se refiere a arrays, ocurre cuando intentas acceder a un índice que no existe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79165/29967), puede que se refiera a cuando intentas leer los índices de `$arreglo`.