# Consulta if(isset($_GET['id'])) { }

Tags: php

Buenas tardes. Hice un sitio web en el que incluí los precios de las clases de inglés usando "Switch" y luego agregando un condicional que verifique que la variable GET está declarada: `if(isset($_GET['id'])) { //código }`
Me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Development\index.php on line 118

Notice: Undefined variable: number in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Development\index.php on line 145

Notice: Undefined variable: duration in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Development\index.php on line 148

Notice: Undefined variable: price in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web Development\index.php on line 151

No puedo identificar el problema. Éste es mi código:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        switch ($_GET['id']) {
            case '1l':
                $number = '1 lesson';
                
                $duration = '1 hour';
                
                $price = 'usd 6';
                break;
            case '6l':
                $number = '6 lessons';
                
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                
                $price = 'usd 34';
                break;
            case '12l':
                $number = '12 lessons';
                
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                
                $price = 'usd 68';
                break;
           }}
           ?>
        <div id="cont_pricing">
            <div id="txt_pricing">
            <p>
                <?php echo $number; ?>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $duration; ?>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <?php echo $price; ?>
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Quisiera saber cómo resolver el problema. Gracias

Comment: Cuando no está aignada `$_GET['id']` se salta el bloque if y entonces encuentra las variables sin definir...

Comment: ¿Cuál es la linea 118? Por otra parte, como bien señala @FranciscoJavier, no hay coherencia en tu código, no puedes pasar a un bloque sin que haya variables sin definir. Entonces, o das a un valor por defecto a esas variables, o replanteas totalmente la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: Hola. La línea 118 es: ```switch ($_GET['id'])```

Comment: @A.Cedano no tenemos una pregunta canonica sobre Undefined variable? es como un NPE en java o en c#... no deberiamos hacer una?

Comment: @gbianchi no sé si [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79165/29967) podría ser ¿? Aunque trata de otros primos y hermanos...

Comment: @A.Cedano podria ser.. pero yo apuntaria mas a algo mas pedagogico sobre causas y posibles soluciones, como tienen las otras.. aca claramente, id, no viene nunca en el get.. por lo cual, no importa como escriba el codigo, si no controla eso, no va a funcionar nada.. el resto, es lo mismo.. nunca se declaran (o porque el codigo falla, o porque declarar dentro de un switch es una pesima idea)

Comment: @gbianchi en ese caso me parece una buena idea lo que propones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verificar con `isset` siempre es recomendable, de lo contrario, tendrás un *`Undefined index`* si intentas a acceder a una clave del `$_GET` que no existe.

Por otra parte, no puedes intentar usar variables sin definirlas previamente, por lo que puedes definir los valores de dichas variables en el `default`.

Pero, así no queda resuelta la parte del `else` (porque el código no entraría en el bloque `switch`), debido a que tienes un `if`, el cual es innecesario si quieres asignar valores por defecto. El `if` tendría sentido si quisieras mostrar otra cosa distinta desde el `else` o dirigir el código por otro camino en ese caso o mostrar un mensaje de error.

En cualquier caso, yo lo resolvería usando un array, es más simple y más fácil de mantener.

Veamos todos los casos:

### 1. Con array, mostrando valores por defecto

```
/*
    Esto reemplaza a los case ...
    Si hubiera situaciones nuevas, solamente las agregas aquí
*/

$allData=
    array(
             '1l'=> array(
                'number' => '1 lesson',
                'duration' => '1 hour',
                'price' => 'usd 6'),
             '6l' => array(
                'number' => '6 lessons',
                'duration' => '1 hour each lesson',
                'price' => 'usd 34'),
            '12l' => array (
                'number' => '12 lessons',
                'duration' => '1 hour each lesson',
                'price' => 'usd 68'),
             'default' => array (
                'number' => '',
                'duration' => '',
                'price' => '')
    );

/*
   Obtienes la key desde el GET
   mediante operador de fusion de null
   si tu versión de PHP no lo soporta, usa esto en su lugar
   $key=!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'default';
*/
$key=$_GET['id'] ?? 'default';
$html=sprintf(
'<div id="cont_pricing">
    <div id="txt_pricing">
        <p>
            %s                
            <br/>
            <br/>
            %s
            <br/>
            <br/>
            %s
         </p>
     </div>
</div>',$allData[$key]['number'],$allData[$key]['duration'],$allData[$key]['price']);
echo $html;
```

### 2. Con array y else (no hay valores por defecto)

```
/*
    Esto reemplaza a los case ...
    Si hubiera situaciones nuevas, solamente las agregas aquí
*/

$allData=
    array(
             '1l'=> array(
                'number' => '1 lesson',
                'duration' => '1 hour',
                'price' => 'usd 6'),
             '6l' => array(
                'number' => '6 lessons',
                'duration' => '1 hour each lesson',
                'price' => 'usd 34'),
            '12l' => array (
                'number' => '12 lessons',
                'duration' => '1 hour each lesson',
                'price' => 'usd 68')
    );

/*
   Obtienes la key desde el GET
   mediante operador de fusion de null
   si tu versión de PHP no lo soporta, usa esto en su lugar
   $key=!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'default';
*/

$key=$_GET['id'] ?? null;
if (array_key_exists($key, $allData)) {
    $html=sprintf(
    '<div id="cont_pricing">
        <div id="txt_pricing">
            <p>
                %s                
                <br/>
                <br/>
                %s
                <br/>
                <br/>
                %s
             </p>
         </div>
    </div>',$allData[$key]['number'],$allData[$key]['duration'],$allData[$key]['price']);
} else {
    $html="Error. La clave $key no es válida";
}
echo $html;
```

---

### 3. Con `switch` (y valores por defecto)

```
/*
   Obtienes la key desde el GET
   mediante operador de fusion de null
   si tu versión de PHP no lo soporta, usa esto en su lugar
   $key=!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'default';
*/
$key=$_GET['id'] ?? 'default';

      switch ($key) {
            case '1l':
                $number = '1 lesson';
                $duration = '1 hour';
                $price = 'usd 6';
                break;
            case '6l':
                $number = '6 lessons';
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                $price = 'usd 34';
                break;
            case '12l':
                $number = '12 lessons';
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                $price = 'usd 68';
                break;
             default:
                $number = '';
                $duration = '';
                $price = '';
             break;
           }

$html=sprintf(
'<div id="cont_pricing">
    <div id="txt_pricing">
        <p>
            %s                
            <br/>
            <br/>
            %s
            <br/>
            <br/>
            %s
         </p>
     </div>
</div>',$number, $duration, $price);

echo $html;
```

### 4. Con `switch` (y else y valores por defecto)

```
/*
   Obtienes la key desde el GET
   mediante operador de fusion de null
   si tu versión de PHP no lo soporta, usa esto en su lugar
   $key=!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'default';
*/

$key=$_GET['id'] ?? null;

if ($key) {
    
      switch ($key) {
            case '1l':
                $number = '1 lesson';
                $duration = '1 hour';
                $price = 'usd 6';
                break;
            case '6l':
                $number = '6 lessons';
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                $price = 'usd 34';
                break;
            case '12l':
                $number = '12 lessons';
                $duration = '1 hour each lesson';
                $price = 'usd 68';
                break;
             default:
                $number = '';
                $duration = '';
                $price = '';
             break;
           }
    
    $html=sprintf(
   '<div id="cont_pricing">
        <div id="txt_pricing">
            <p>
                %s                
                <br/>
                <br/>
                %s
                <br/>
                <br/>
                %s
             </p>
         </div>
    </div>',$number, $duration, $price);
} else {
    $html="Error. No se pasaron datos válidos";
}
echo $html;
```

De cualquiera de estas formas tu código debería funcionar. Lo fundamental es que:

- Deberías primero capturar el valor del dato que viene en el `$_GET`, con un ternario o de otro modo.
- Si usas `switch ... case` deberías prever la situación del `default`
- Si ninguna condición se cumple, debes tener claro qué debe hacer el código en ese caso (por ejemplo, en el caso `4` si el GET tiene una clave `id` pero que no vale ninguno de los case, el código tomará los valores por defecto, y sólo entrará en el `else` cuando el GET no tenga una clave `id`).

Comment: Hola A.Cedano. Probé con el ejemplo 1 "Con array, mostrando valores por defecto" y quedó perfecto. Te agradezco un montón por tu ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: @CintiaT me alegro de que te haya servido. La gran ventaja de esa solución es que si hubiera una situación nueva, solamente la agregas a `$allData` y no tienes que hacer más cambios en el código.

Comment: Si la respuesta ha servido para solucionar tu problema considera marcarla como aceptada, de modo que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver y la respuesta dada pueda servir a futuros usuarios con un problema similar. Saludos.