# Permitir el paso de variables desde URL

Tags: php, html, variables, variables-globales

requiero de su apoyo.

Tengo un pequeño script para rastrear productos a través de Internet, el script funciona bien, pero para poder rastrear algo forzosamente el cliente debe ingresar los datos en el formulario.

Me interesaria que también se pudiese hacer desde la propia URL, que se les diera una dirección tipo https://rastreo.web.mx/index.php?carrier=estafeta&shipment=2663616575 y se le abra su rastreo directamente sin ingresar datos.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

```
     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-app">
<fieldset class="row">

<!-- Heading -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="legend">Rastreo de Paquetes</h3>
</div>


<!-- Select List -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="carrier">Paquetería</label>
        <select id="carrier" name="carrier" data-alias=""  class="form-control" required  >
            <option value="" >Seleccione una opción</option>
            <option value="99 Minutos" >99 Minutos</option>
            <option value="FedEx" >FedEx</option>
            <option value="DHL" >DHL</option>
            <option value="Redpack" >Redpack</option>
            <option value="Estafeta" >Estafeta</option>
            <option value="UPS" >UPS</option>
            <option value="iVoy" >iVoy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Number -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="number">Número de guía</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipment" name="shipment" value="" data-alias="" data-integer-only="true"  class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-action">
        <button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="" style="display:none"><label class="control-label" for="_email">Disculpe, pero deje este campo en blanco</label><input type="text" id="_email" class="form-control" name="_email"></div> </form>
<div id="respuesta">
</div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<center>
<?php

//Verificar si el POST está configurado
if (isset($_POST["carrier"])) {

//Obtener el valor de los campos
include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

//Crear una nueva instancia de la clase
$params = array(
  "api_key" => $API_KEY,
  "carrier" => $carrier,
  "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
);

$headers = array(
  "api_key=".$API_KEY
);
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));

//Ejecutar la petición
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Mostrar la respuesta
$respuesta = json_decode($response);
//Mostrar la respuesta en formato HTML con tablas alidando si el status es SUCCESS 

if($respuesta->status=="SUCCESS"){
  echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>";
  echo "<h4 class='alert-heading'>¡Envío encontrado!</h4>";
  echo "<p>El envío con número de guía <strong>".$shipment_number."</strong> fue encontrado con éxito.</p>";
  
//Mostrar logotipo de la paquetería seleccionada si no hay logo se muestra logo de 4huellitas

  if($carrier=="99 Minutos"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/99minutos.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='99 Minutos'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="FedEx"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/fedex.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='FedEx'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="DHL"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/dhl.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='DHL'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="Redpack"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/redpack.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='Redpack'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="Estafeta"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/estafeta.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='Estafeta'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="UPS"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/ups.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='UPS'><br>";
  }
  elseif($carrier=="iVoy"){
    echo "<br><img src='https://cdn-client.solucionesmarva.com/CU2012-00046/img/ivoy.svg' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='iVoy'><br>";
  }
  else{
    echo "<br><img src='https://tienda4huellitas.mx/wp-content/webpc-passthru.php?src=https://tienda4huellitas.mx/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/4huellitas-small.png&nocache=1' width='150' class='d-inline-block align-top' alt='4Huellitas'><br>";
  }

echo "<br>";
echo "<table border='1'>";

//Mostrar estado del envio, color del estado cambia dependiendo el estado del mismo

if($respuesta->status_code=="1"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #00B3FC; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="2"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="3"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="13"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #00B3FC; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="14"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #02AA30; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="15"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="16"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #00B3FC; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="17"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="40"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="50"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #02AA30; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="51"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="90"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #FF1A1A; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
elseif($respuesta->status_code=="98"){
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #FF1A1A; color: white;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}
else{
  echo "<tr><td>Estado del envío</td><td style='background-color: #E6E645; color: black;'>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
}

//Se muestran el resto de datos en formato de tabla

echo "<tr><td>Fecha estimada de entrega</td><td>".$respuesta->expected_delivery_date."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".date("d/m/Y H:i:s A", strtotime($respuesta->pickup_date))."</td></tr>";

//Mostrar los detalles del envio en una tabla HTML y cambiar el formato de fecha a dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM
echo "<tr><td>Seguimiento</td><td><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Comentarios</td></tr>";
foreach($respuesta->checkpoints as $checkpoint){
  echo "<tr><td>".date("d/m/Y H:i:s A", strtotime($checkpoint->date))."</td><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->comments."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>";
    echo "<h4 class='alert-heading'>¡Envío no encontrado!</h4>";
    echo "<p>El envío con número de guía <strong>".$shipment_number."</strong> no fue encontrado.</p>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<p class='mb-0'>Por favor, intente de nuevo.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
    }
//}

?>
```

Como información adicional el var_dump($_GET) me muestra lo siguiente:

```
array(2) { ["carrier"]=> string(8) "estafeta" ["shipment"]=> string(10) "2663616575" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La URL: `https://rastreo.web.mx/index.php?carrier=estafeta&shipment=2663616575` es ya en sí misma una petición `GET` dirigida en este caso al archivo `index.php`.

Cuando se procesa esa URL, el servidor debería recibir en la super global `$_GET`<sup>1</sup> un array como este:

```
$_GET=array(
             "carrier"=>"estafeta",
             "shipment"=>2663616575
            );
```

Si en `index.php` tú pones, para probar:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Y escribes la URL de más arriba, deberías ver la constitución del array con los datos pasados en la URL.

Dicho eso, puedes procesar los datos recibidos del mismo modo que haces en tu código mostrado, **pero cambiando `$_POST`<sup>2</sup> por `$_GET`** y excluyendo el `form`, el cual no será necesario, porque la URL hace las veces del `form`.

Por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_GET["carrier"])) {

    //Obtener el valor de los campos
    include_once "key.php";
    $shipment_number=$_GET["shipment"];
    $carrier=$_GET["carrier"];
    
    //Crear una nueva instancia de la clase
    $params = array(
      "api_key" => $API_KEY,
      "carrier" => $carrier,
      "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
    );
    
    $headers = array(
      "api_key=".$API_KEY
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
    ));
    // etc ...
```

#### Algunas observaciones

1. Veo que tienes declarado el `form` como *multipart*, lo cual se usa cuando, aparte de datos llanos (cadenas, números) quieres enviar otras partes, como archivos adjuntos. Si es el caso, no podrás hacerlo por la URL, para ello necesitarás sí o sí un formulario o usar la API FormData de Javascript. Para más detalles ver [**Subida con el método POST**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php) en el Manual de PHP.
2. Aunque en el ejemplo he supuesto que tus peticiones van dirigidas y procesadas en el archivo `index.php`, lo habitual es usar `index.php` como punto de entrada de la aplicación y desde él redirigir las peticiones a diferentes partes de la aplicación, usando URL amigables (ver por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/306018/29967)), rutas, etc. Este es un tema amplio y existen distintas herramientas y frameworks para ponerlo en práctica. Procesar todo desde `index.php` puede ser factible para una aplicación sencilla, pero en una aplicación grande sería complicado controlar desde ahí todas las rutas.
3. Convendría que verifiques el estado de tus datos antes de pasar a usarlos, de lo contrario te estarías exponiendo a casos de *`Undefined index`* o de *`Undefined offset`*. <sup>3</sup>
4. Los datos que ingresan al servidor desde una fuente externa cualquiera: URL, formularios, archivos, etc pueden ser explotados por usuarios mal intencionados para perpetrar ataques en el servidor, y estos ataques pueden ser de cualquier tipo<sup>4</sup>: desde suplantar identidad, sustraer información o modificarla, escalar niveles de acceso superior en la base de datos o en el servidor mismo, cargar archivos dañinos en el servidor, etc. Conviene pues que en algunos casos apliques filtros de saneamiento<sup>5</sup>, que en otros casos apliques consultas preparadas<sup>6</sup> etc, sin caer en paranoias como filtrar indiscriminadamente. Por ejemplo, una entrada que se usará solamente en una consulta SQL no necesita ser saneada, sino simplemente usar una consulta preparada con esos datos. El responsable del saneamiento en ese caso, se la herramienta de preparación de consultas.

Con esto tu problema actual queda resuelto y tienes herramientas para profundizar, para escribir un código no sólo funcional sino también seguro.

Si tienes dudas pregunta en comentarios, **soy humano, no soy una IA**.

---

#### Notas

1. Ver [la super global `$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) en el Manual de PHP.
2. Ver [la super global `$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) en el Manual de PHP.
3. Ver la pregunta: *[PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”, “Notice: Undefined index”, y “Notice: Undefined offset” ¿Qué quiere decir?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79165/29967)*
4. Ver las inquietantes respuestas a la pregunta: *[¿La Inyección SQL actúa sólo a nivel de la base de datos o el riesgo es aún mayor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108520/29967)*, para evitar banalizar el riesgo de inyección de código.
5. Ver [filtros de saneamiento](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php) en el Manual de PHP.
6. Ver [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) en el Manual de PHP y la pregunta: *[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)*