# Petición jQuery Ajax devuelve siempre null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando recoger un string que devuelve un fichero .php haciendo una llamada Ajax. Pero siempre entra en success, sin embargo el dato que devuelve es siempre null. A qué se debe?? Estoy aprendiendo y no sé muy bien qué hago mal...

El código que he intentado:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/administrator/components/views/response.php',
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    request: result.id
                }
            }).success(function (data) {

                console.log("Success. Data: "+ data);

            }).error(function (error, responseText) {
                console.log("Error. "+ error);

            });
```

El archivo response.php tan solo contiene:

```
return "Texto de prueba";
```

El realidad necesito que el archivo .php haga unos cálculos y los devuelva, pero primero necesito resolver el problema de que ni siquiera devuelva algo de ejemplo...

Comment: Hola Norak, debes codificar el `return` de tipo json en tu caso seria algo como `$arr = array ('variable'=>'Texto de prueba'); echo json_encode($arr);` para mostrarlo en el console.log seria `console.log("Success. Data: "+ data.variable);`

Comment: El archivo PHP debe **sacar por pantalla la respuesta**, con `echo, print, print_r` u otro. `return` no implica una salida por pantalla. Luego, esa salida por pantalla **debe ser conforme al `dataType` que has indicado en Ajax**. Si quieres un `json`, entonces la respuesta debe ser un `json`, si quieres salida normal, puedes poner `html`  en el `dataType`.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra ayuda! He seguido vuestras indicaciones y ha funcionado! Tiene que ser coherente el dataType y no lo estaba haciendo bien. Quería json y pasaba un string. Gracias! (me sirven como respuestas válidas, podrían publicarlo como solución)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo muy importante a tener en cuenta cuando lanzas peticiones al servidor por medio de Ajax es el `dataType` que indicas.

Si tú indicas que es `json`, entonces, ocurra lo que ocurra en el servidor, la respuesta del mismo **debe ser únicamente un resultado json**, ya que si tú envías otro tipo de respuesta el código no funcionará como se espera.

Tu programa podría quedar entonces así:

### JS/jQuery

He aprovechado para usar `done` y `fail`, dado que `success` y `error` son obsoletos desde jQuery 3.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/administrator/components/views/response.php',
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    request: result.id
                }
            }).done(function (data) {

                console.log("Success. Data: "+ data);
                console.log("Success. Data: "+ data.status);

            }).fail(function (error, responseText) {
                console.log("Error. "+ error);

            });
```

### PHP

Aquí yo creo una variable `$arrRespuesta` que irá recogiendo información sobre el resultado de lo ocurrido y al final imprimiré esa variable en forma de json, tal y como lo está esperando Ajax.

Otra cosa importante es poner un header con el tipo de dato y la codificación. Si esto no está el código podría fallar, por ejemplo, si hay caracteres especiales en los datos que producirían un json inválido.

```
$arrRespuesta=array();

if (isset($_POST["request"])){

    $arrRespuesta["status"]="Correcto. Hemos recibido el valor: ".$_POST['request'];

}else{

    $arrRespuesta["status"]="Incorrecto. No se posteó el valor esperado en request";

}

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($arrRespuesta);
```

Nótese que en este ejemplo el array que se devuelve tendrá siempre una clave `status` y que en el `done` de Ajax he añadido otro `console.log`, para mostrar que puedes acceder al mensaje que hay dentro de la clave del json, mediante la propiedad `status` del mismo :) .

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Mil gracias! Solución perfecta. He resuelto mi error y me has aclarado mucho mis dudas

Comment: Lo único que no entiendo el uso de `print_r` para este caso. Seria preferible utilizar `print` o `echo` ya que estos son contrucciones del lenguaje y por lo tanto mas eficientes.

Comment: @Xerif la verdad que no había considerado ese punto, suelo usar `print_r()` por costumbre, cuando efectivamente, en las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/72719/29967)  se dice que `echo` es más rápido. Editando código... Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te envío otra forma de trabajar con peticiones ajax... para mi, quizás más cómoda.

"index.php"
no olvides agregar el jquery.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  datosEnviar = "datos que quieras mandar";
  $.post("response.php?op=1", {datosRecibir: datosEnviar}, function (resultado)
  {
    console.log(resultado)
  })
</script>
```

"response.php"

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['op']) {
    case 1: 
       $datosRecibidos =$_POST["datosRecibir"];
       echo "texto enviado";
   break;
}
?>
```

$.post("response.php?op=XXX" Envias las peticiones que desees a lo largo del proyecto.

switch ($_GET['op']) {
    case XXXX: recoges la variable que envias, y procedes a desarrollar el código para cada una de las peticiones enviadas
    break;
 }

Comment: Cesar ¿te diste cuenta de que tu código es incoherente? Mandas un `post` y lo recoges con un `get` y luego vuelves a usar `post` para `datosRecibir`  ¿?.  Además, como lo tiene es mucho más claro y mejor configurable, para indicar el tipo de dato que quiere recibir y además se puede incorporar una función para manejar los posibles errores que ocurran en la petición.

Comment: No es incoherente. Tiene su lógica, te la explico.... Se entiende que el archivo response.php, es un archivo que recoge solamente peticiones ajax. Con las variables GET, te posicionas dentro de la opción deseada dentro del switch. Ejemplo op=1, podría ser para el código de logeo. op=2 para el codigo de deslogeo... Cada una lanzada con un evento clic en un boton !=... Las variables post, son las  variables u objetos que mandas desde tu script... Te recomiendo que lo pruebes y compruebes, que no solo funciona, sino que tiene coherencia. El usar variables get no excluye el uso de variables post

Comment: @A.Cedano realmente el ejemplo no es incoherente, envía datos por ambos métodos get y post. No obstante creo que la respuesta no es la más adecuada. Pienso que deberías publicar tu comentario anterior como respuesta, ya que es la solución que más se adapta a la pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: @Xerif puede que la respuesta que he dado no sea la que más se le acerque al problema. En mi favor, he de decir, que he iniciado el post con el siguiente texto: "Te envío otra forma de trabajar con peticiones ajax... para mi quizás más cómoda." Llevo años trabajando de esta forma, y seguramente, por el habito, me parezca mas comoda (seguramente no la mas eficiente o profesional, pero si efectiva) Un saludo.