# ¿Cómo imprimo variables en HTML que provienen de un código PHP?

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos

estoy desarrollando una web en la que un usuario se logea, y sus datos quedan subidos a una base de datos, a la vez que esos mismos datos quedan en una variable de PHP almacenados, con una sesión abierta, lo que yo quiero hacer, una vez logeado el usuario, es poder imprimir esas variables y manipularlas desde HTML, por ejemplo: Cuando el usuario inicia sesión, el usuario queda guardado en la variable `$Usuario`, ahora yo, quiero poder imprimir y manipular esa variable desde mi `index.html` (que es a donde se dirige el usuario cuando se logea) al igual que poder manipular por ejemplo una imagen, la cual esta guardada en el código php con la variable `$img`.

Les dejo un ejemplo con código (es un código resumido, solo muestro las líneas interesantes, lo otro es relevante)

en `login.php`

```
$Usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["Usuario"]);
$_SESSION['usuario']=$Usuario;
```

en `index.html`

"Acá quiero imprimir la variable que proviene desde PHP, la cual seria $Usuario"
La quiero imprimir usando por ejemplo la etiqueta p

Espero haberme explicado, y que puedan ayudarme, saludos y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Que tiene que ver `css` aqui, y para mostrar en `HTML` es `echo-print, etc` si quieres saber la diferencia, aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/72719/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-echo-print-print-r-var-dump-y-var-export-en-php

Comment: Como te dicen puedes escribir con echo y este permite html markups.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, para que puedas trabajar con `PHP` en tu documento `HTML` deberías guardar dichas páginas con la extensión `.php` y no `.htm` o `.html` o debes configurar tu servidor para que ejecute tus archivos **HTML** como archivos **PHP**. Aunque te aconsejo el primero.

Comment: Una vez hayas guardado tus páginas con la extensión PHP, para imprimir una variable debes abrir y cerrar la etiqueta de **PHP**, ejemplo: `<?php  ?>`, y luego para imprimir una variable, seria `<?php echo "<p>$variable</p>"; ?>` https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro-whatis.php

Comment: Tienes dos opciones, una es cambiar la extensión del fichero .html para que sea .php, aunque eso depende del servidor y su configuración, hecho esto, puedes intercalar código php entre el html, por ejemplo, <?=$Usuario?> imprimirá el contenido de la variable $Usuario. Por otro lado, tienes la opción de usar ajax y tratar los datos en javascript, con una llamada ajax a un .php, te devuelve las variables que desees por ejemplo en json y luego en javascript, las imprimes donde quieras.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas!, lo de cambiar .html a .php es algo que me ayuda a resolver mi situación y lo cual ya había probado, ahora la cuestión es la siguiente, supónganse que yo a la imagen quiero imprimirla en la esquina de mi pagina y con un border-radius o cualquier otra propiedad de css, es decir, no quiero que la muestre en cualquier lado y de cualquier manera, hay forma de modificar esta imagen que esta dada por un echo <?php echo "<p>$img</p>"; ?> ?

Comment: @GonzaloRamirez eso es una nueva pregunta, por favor revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: A la imagen simplemente le podrías dar estilos `css`, es decir, `<?php echo "<img class='estilo_imagen' src='$ruta_img' />"; ?>` mediante el atributo **class** o **id** de `css`.

Comment: @D.Bulten Gracias! saludos.

Answer (score 0):

como requisito para hacerlo necesitas:

- que tu archivo `html` tenga extensión `php`.
- otra alternativa es que tu servidor web pueda ver los archivos con extensión `html` y pueda interpretar el código `php` dentro.

A partir de esto donde quiera imprimir algo `php` puedes hacer esto:

- Short print (si esta soportado por tu servidor):

`<?=$foo?>`

- Impresión mediante apertura de tag normal:

`<?php echo $foo; ?>`

En esta pagina podrás encontrar los ejemplos que te he dado:
https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-use-php-in-html-code--cms-34378